# SQL Optimize query to get max value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query. The part where I do the

```
     select for max(Entered_On).....
```

takes the longest. If I comment out the where cause, it run fast.

```
      Select   dlp.ParamID, dp.ParamName   
      from data_LocP  dlp 
      inner join data_In  di on dlp.LocID = di.LocID
      inner join data_Parms dp on dp.ParamID = di.ParamID
      inner join map_Loc ml on ml.LocId =  dlp.LocId
      where di.Entered_On = (select max(Entered_On ) from data_In where LocId = dlp.LocID
      and ParamId = dlp.ParamID)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to optimize this query as the part where I get the Max(Entered_On) takes the longest time. As a FYI, I need the Entered_On to be the max date for a given LocId and ParamId.

Here is a more extended code but does not give the max:

```
      select   *  FROM
      (
        SELECT dlp.ParamID, dp.ParamName, dlp.LocID,  ml.LocName , di.Entered_On, (GETUTCDATE() -  dlp.FreqDays) DueDate, dlp.FreqDays,  
        a.CompanyId, a.SiteID, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dlp.LocId, dlp.ParamID 
                          ORDER BY di.Entered_On DESC)
             as RowNum            

      from data_LocParams dlp 
      inner join data_Input di on dlp.LocID = di.LocID
      inner join data_Parameters dp on dp.ParamID = di.ParamID
      inner join map_Locations ml on ml.LocId =  dlp.LocId
      left join
     (
       select ml.LocId,ms.CompanyId, ms.SiteId  
       from map_Sites ms 
       join map_WaterSystems mw
       on ms.SiteID = mw.SiteID
       join map_Locations ml
       on ml.SysID = mw.SysID
      ) a 
      on a.LocId = dlp.LocID   
      where   dlp.FreqDays is not null AND dlp.FreqDays <> ''      
   ) as a WHERE a.RowNum = 1 and Entered_On < (GETUTCDATE() -   FreqDays)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT   dlp.ParamID, dp.ParamName, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dlp.LocId, dlp.ParamID 
                              ORDER BY di.Entered_On) as RowNum
  FROM data_LocP  dlp 
  JOIN data_In  di on dlp.LocID = di.LocID
  JOIN data_Parms dp on dp.ParamID = di.ParamID
  JOIN map_Loc ml on ml.LocId =  dlp.LocId
) WHERE RowNum = 1
```

If you have multiple records that can match the same `Entered_On` value, then use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Why didn't you use max(entered_on) instead of row_number?

Comment: @Wirus that give you the max per LocId and Paramid for every record, and you wouldn't be able to tell which paramname that was associated with the max(entered_on)

Comment: @Conrad - I put a more extended code (Please look above) but seems like I cannot get it to work based on ROW_NUMBER().. It runs but I do not get the Entered-On for a given LocId ParamID. Do you know what I am doing wrong..

Comment: Hmm well `di.entered_on < ( Getutcdate() - dlp.freqdays ) )` gets processed before the ROWNUM = 1. is that really what you want?

Comment: Conrad I modified the code as shown above but I am getting the same Entered_On for a given LocID. It seems like it is not doing it for a given ParamID, LocID

Comment: @Conrad - aa, ok, I just focused on row_number part not on entire query. With fresh mind it's clear :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to any changes to the SQL SELECT, try building an index with `Entered_On` in `DESC` order. This should help with any query that needs to sort on Entered_On DESC or pull MAX of Entered_On.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_entered_on ON data_in
(
    LocId, ParamId, Entered_On DESC
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You say "I need the Entered_On to be the max date for a given LocId and ParamId", but you don't specify any values for those fields.  Something like:

```
where locId = something
and ParamId = something
```

in both the main query and subquery will get you what you say you want and will do so very quickly.